# How to remove boiler plate code

Tags: haskell

I would like to reduce the following boiler plate code, BUT without using lenses (Data.Label). How could I best do this?

```
data Qcfg = Qcfg { qthresh :: Int, tdelay :: Rational, cwpsq :: TPSQ, cwmap :: TMap, cwchan :: TChan String }

getQthresh = do
   c <- ask
   return (qthresh c)

getDelay = do
   c <- ask
   return (tdelay c)

getTMap = do
   c <- ask
   return (cwmap c)

getTPsq = do
   c <- ask
   return (cwpsq c)

getTChan = do
    c <- ask
    return (cwchan c)
```

Comment: Is `getDelay = asks tdelay` etc. good enough?

Comment: @DanielFischer I hoped to combine it somehow into one simple function.

Comment: @JFritsch, one function? So you would write `foo <- getField` and Haskell would just *guess* which field you meant? How do you mean that it should work?

Comment: @dflemstr I am asking to see whether someone knows anything to improve this by removing the boiler plate code and achieving the same functionality. I ask because in Haskell there are probably many things I have not even heard off. If I would know it all myself ... then ... I guises I would not ask. In deed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are just cases of fmap.  These are all equivalent:

```
getQthresh = qthresh <$> ask

getQthresh'' = fmap qthresh ask

getQthresh''' = liftM qthresh ask

getQthresh' = do
   c <- ask
   return (qthresh c)
```

The `Data.Functor` / `Control.Applicative` version with `<$>` is the one you want; there is no boilerplate in it at all if you think about it. And you are indeed wasting space writing functions for each accessor; you just *a new way to apply the accessors* which `fmap/<$>` gives you. If you are forever writing `<$> ask` you can define

```
 get field = field <$> ask
```

Maybe that's what you were looking for now that I think of it. Then

```
get qthresh
```

will be the same as your

```
getQthresh
```

and similarly for the other fields.  Of course you could define this `get` (note that State goes with a different one) in your monadic way:

```
get field = do
   c <- ask
   return (field c)
```

For the specific case of `Reader` there is `asks f` which is `fmap f ask`, and likewise `gets` for `State`, but I was taking the question to be about 'lifting' accessors into a functor or monad, since it seemed it wasnt plain that `do {x <- action; return (f x)}` is just `f <$> action`